# Some programs are not working after changing the motherboard

Tags: 20.04

When I changed the motherboard, some programs stopped working On my Ubuntu 20.04. I didn't reinstall OS and the motherboard is nearly the same as the old one and a lot of programs are not working after that. I did reinstall those programs but the issue persists. Some of the applications are VLC player, Super Mario, etc.

Comment: Which programs? How do they "not work"? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: when I clicked with the mouse it didn't turn on
  at all

Comment: ... and what happens if you open a terminal and try to run `vlc` (or `cvlc`) from there?

Comment: thank you for steeldriver your answer ...I am new whit ununtu and the terminal as well please tell me what exactly  must to right on the terminal to run the programs ? I usually ru the programs from applications .I need to run super mario Bros and VLC payer .thanks in advise

Comment: when I run from  the terminal that  happening    X Error:  BadAlloc
  Request Major code 146 ()
  Request Minor code 7
  Error Serial #100
  Current Serial #101

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation for the cause your problems is it's a hardware issue caused by improperly installing or connecting peripheral devices to the new motherboard. Fortunately you don't need to reinstall Ubuntu to diagnose this issue. Boot from the live USB that you used to install Ubuntu. Select the *Try Ubuntu* option to run Ubuntu as a live session. You can also install some of your favorite apps from an Ubuntu live session. If everything works in the live session then your problems are over. You can simply reinstall Ubuntu and it will work OK after that.